AWS Cognito custom access tokens
I have followed this tutorial to use a pre token generation Lambda within AWS Cognito with the intent of customizing the access_token when the app client uses the client_credentials grant type. At the moment this Lambda does not appear to be invoked

AWS UI appears to create a policy to allow Cognito to invoke the Lambda successfully
The Lambda trigger is configured in the user pool properties
The trigger event version is V2_0 (Basic features + access token customization)

When performing a client_credentials grant flow with this configuration, an access token is correctly issued, however there are no customisations added to the token, and the Lambda logs do not indicate this has been triggered.
Is this feature supported for the client credentials flow, if so, how can I troubleshoot?

This feature is not currently supported for client_credentials.. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html#user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation-accesstoken
